# Why does C# use [System.Serializable] for keeping instance? (Unity3D)

Tags: c#, serialization, unity-game-engine

I wanted to make a programme if it take a TextAsset from inspector(it is placed in 'ExampleEditor'), it make a custom data instance for use blendshape animation.

At first I made my custom data class not using [System.Serializable].

```
public class Matrix {
    public int row;
    public int col;
    public double[,] mat;
}
```

My strategy was taking a TextAsset, parsing string from TextAsset and finally making a Matrix instance to a field variable in 'Example.cs'. I thought when it was initialized and assigned first, I was able to use that variable in Example instance. However, It did not work, It threw 'NullReferenceException'.

So I found solution using '[System.Serializable]'. It did work. (and I knew that Unity3D does not provide multi-dimensional array for their serialization method.)

```
using UnityEngine;
using System;
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;

[System.Serializable]
public class Matrix {
    [System.Serializable]
    public class mRow {
        public List<float> aRow = new List<float>();
    }

    [HideInInspector]
    [SerializeField]
    public int row;

    [HideInInspector]
    [SerializeField]
    public int col;

    //[HideInInspector]
    [SerializeField]
    public List<mRow> mat = new List<mRow>();
}
```

Finally, I know the solution, But I don't know why this problem was happened. It is related to GC?

Comment: This question doesn't appear to make sense? The serializable attribute merely tells the compiler that the object in question can be serialized. Properties not marked are not serialized. It's difficult to know what you are trying to achieve / what the problem is exactly from this description.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Your question isn't very clear, but I think to know what you are not understanding.

> My strategy was taking a TextAsset, parsing string from TextAsset and
>   finally making a Matrix instance to a field variable in 'Example.cs'.

You didn't explain how you did that (perhaps call the parsing function from a custom inspector?). 
However, despite on how you managed to initialize a field from the editor, **if the field isn't serializable, it will be null when switching from editor to play mode**.

That happens because when entering play mode, `Unity3D` serializes all `C#` classes populating the relative `C++` classes of the engine. If a field isn't a public field of a type that Unity can serialize (or even a private field marked with a `SerializeFieldAttribute`, always of a type that `Unity` can serialize ), `Unity3D` won't serialize it.

So when you switch to play mode the reference will be null.

In other word, all fields that you want to initialize from the editor MUST be serializable in order to be used in play mode.

```
[SerializeField]
public List<mRow> mat = new List<mRow>();
```

The code above doesn't make much sense. If you plan to intialize a serializable field from the inspector don't initialize it by code, otherwise you could eventually lose the reference.
An example of such an error:

```
[SerializeField]
private List<int> aList;

public void Start()
{
  aList = new List<int>();
}
```

The code above will cause troubles. If you had initialized `aList` from inspector, it will be correctly serialized but when you switch in play mode e the `Start` callback is called, `aList` will be reinitialized and you'll end up with a reference to an empty list.

Here's a nice [blog post](http://blogs.unity3d.com/2012/10/25/unity-serialization/) explaining details on how `Unity3D` handle serialization of objects. Read it!

Comment: Here are [some other](http://forum.unity3d.com/threads/155352-Serialization-Best-Practices-Megapost) good [resources](http://docs.unity3d.com/Documentation/ScriptReference/SerializeField.html) for anyone else interested.

Comment: Thanks your answer, "However, despite on how you managed to initialize a field from the editor, if the field isn't serializable, it will be null when switching from editor to play mode." This part was really helpful.